# Obtener VIDEOS con Web Scraping

Tags: html, python, jwplayer

Estoy tratando de obtener la url de un video incrustado en una pagina web ( https://libero.pe/futbol-peruano/liga-1/1537419-youtube-alianza-lima-vs-mannucci-vivo-ver-gol-federico-rodriguez-1-1-mansiche-liga-1-movistar-video-yt ) y lo que logro encontrar en el html es solo esto:

```
src="blob:https://cdn.jwplayer.com/bb56e02e-52cb-452a-9516-a633a0efc6c7"
```

Lo que entiendo es que alojan el video en jwplayer, y pareciese que la url estuviese cifrado o algo asi.... Pero entonces definitivamente me seria imposible obtener dicha url?

Comment: Pista: https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/playlists/cDEGHqlr?recommendations_playlist_id=3JJ1AdqM&search=__CONTEXTUAL__

Comment: Eres el puto amo, a simple vista creo que me puede funcionar, ahora solo me queda pensar un rato en como vincular cada video al articulo correspondiente. Muchas gracias

Comment: Solo una pregunta mas porfavor. Ese json lo encontraste en el mismo html de la pagina?

Comment: Claro, revisando un poco por el código fuente de la página con firefox. Ayuda mucho entender la estructura antes de comenzar a programar para buscarla.